# Oracle. How to output date and time?

Tags: oracle, date, time

My Visit table is the following:

```
insert into Visit
values(12, to_date('19-JUN-13', 'dd-mon-yy'), to_date('19-JUN-13 12:00 A.M.' , 'dd-mon-yy hh:mi A.M.'));
insert into Visit
values(15, to_date('20-JUN-13', 'dd-mon-yy'), to_date('20-JUN-13 02:00 A.M.' , 'dd-mon-yy hh:mi A.M.'));
insert into Visit
values(18, to_date('21-JUN-13', 'dd-mon-yy'), to_date('21-JUN-13 10:30 A.M.' , 'dd-mon-yy hh:mi A.M.'));
```

When i try to query it:
`select * from Visit` i get:

```
SQL> select * from visit;

   SLOTNUM DATEVISIT ACTUALARRIVALTIME                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
---------- --------- ------------------------------                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
        12 19-JUN-13 19-JUN-13                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
        15 20-JUN-13 20-JUN-13                                                                                                                                                                                                       
        18 21-JUN-13 21-JUN-13                                                                                                                                                                                                      

SQL> spool off;
```

How come the time is not there?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

An Oracle `DATE` column stores datetime values accurate to the second. Use [`TO_CHAR`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/TO_CHAR-datetime.html) to format the dates:

```
SELECT
  SLOTNUM,
  TO_CHAR(DATEVISIT, 'MM/DD/YYYY') AS VisitDisp
  TO_CHAR(ACTUALARRIVALTIME, 'MM/DD/YY HH:MI:SS A.M.') AS ArrDisp
FROM Visit
```

The `A.M.` format code yields `A.M.` or `P.M.` depending on the time. You can use `P.M.` as well -- either works.

When inserting date values in script, IMO it's cleaner to use [DATE and TIMESTAMP literals](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/Literals.html#GUID-8F4B3F82-8821-4071-84D6-FBBA21C05AC1):

```
INSERT INTO Visit VALUES (
  12,
  DATE '2013-06-19',
  TIMESTAMP '2013-06-19 00:00:00');

INSERT INTO Visit VALUES (
  12,
  DATE '2013-06-20',
  TIMESTAMP '2013-06-20 02:00:00');

INSERT INTO Visit VALUES (
  12,
  DATE '2013-06-21',
  TIMESTAMP '2013-06-21 10:30:00');
```

For a "PM" time just use the 24-hour clock:

```
-- Time for the third column is 4:25 PM
INSERT INTO Visit VALUES (
  12,
  DATE '2013-06-22',
  TIMESTAMP '2013-06-22 16:25:00');
```

You can also set a format that applies to *all* dates like this:

```
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'DD-MON-YYYY HH:MI:SS PM';
```

That way, your original query would output the dates in the format you're after, without using `TO_CHAR`. To set back to the usual default format, just do this:

```
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'DD-MON-RR';
```

Comment: Should it be HH:MI:SS instead of HH:M:SS?

Comment: Correct @MaximEliseev, and thanks for letting me know! That was a typo. I've updated the answer with your fix.

Comment: Is there a way to make that the default setting?

Comment: If you mean so that it will be the Oracle format for all sessions and keep that setting even if Oracle is stopped and restarted, you'll need DBA privileges. More information [here](http://dba-oracle.com/t_how_to_change_the_default_data_format.htm)

Answer (score 25):

that is the oracle date format that is set as the default for your instance.

you should properly specify the format to see more or less.. something like this:

```
select to_char( datevisit, 'dd-mon-yy hh24:mi:ss' ) from visit
```

Comment: Thanks, then i cannot use `select * `, can i...? I have to list all the columns: `select col1, col2, to_char(...) from visit` ?? is that right?

Comment: @Buras - you can use `select *` if you issue an `alter session`, as Ed Gibbs showed.

Answer (score 3):

Oracle internally follow 'DD-Mon-YY' format to store in database. So it returns'DD-Mon-Y

If you want to date format with hours min and sec. you can alter NLS_DATE_FORMAT in session.

If you want to query for the just Presentation purpose for that instance. Use TO_char Function to convert into required format.

```
SELECT slotnum, TO_CHAR (datevisit, 'DD-MON-YY ') "DATEVISIT",
       TO_CHAR (actualarrivaltime, 'DD-MON-YY HH:MI:SS AM') "ACTUALARRIVALTIME"
  FROM visit
```

I Hope the above query gives you the output as you like.

Comment: Dates are not *stored* in DD-Mon-YY or any other human-readable format. Oracle uses its own [7-byte internal representation](http://stackoverflow.com/a/187492/266304) to store dates.

Answer (score 2):

You're relying on implicit date conversion, which is using your (session-dependent, but maybe inherited from the DB default) `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` setting - in this case that seems to be `DD-MON-RR`.

You can use `to_char` to specify the format, e.g.:

```
select to_char(actualarrivaltime, 'DD-MON-YYYY HH:M:SS PM') from ..
```

The [datetime format models are described in the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/sql_elements004.htm#i34924).

In general it's better to never rely on implcit conversions. Even if you get what you expect now, they can be session-specific so another user in another client ,ight see something different. This can cause failures as well as just look wrong. Always specify date and number formats, using `to_date`, `to_char`, `to_timestamp` etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
select localtimestamp from dual;
```