# Oracle SQL Next_day not being grouped

Tags: sql, oracle

```
select
  next_day(zebra_time, 'mon'),
from builds
where
    zebra_time >= '01-jan-2014'
group by next_day(zebra_time, 'mon');
```

zebra_time's datatype is DATE

Result:
06-JAN-14
06-JAN-14
06-JAN-14
06-JAN-14
06-JAN-14
06-JAN-14
06-JAN-14
06-JAN-14
06-JAN-14
06-JAN-14
06-JAN-14
06-JAN-14
06-JAN-14
06-JAN-14
06-JAN-14
06-JAN-14

why arent they being grouped?
Shouldnt there be just one 06-JAN-14?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `DATE` type contains time even if it is not displayed.

```
select
  trunc(next_day(zebra_time, 'mon'))
from builds
where
    zebra_time >= '01-jan-2014'
group by trunc(next_day(zebra_time, 'mon'));
```

You can use `trunc` to remove the time portion of the date and get the grouping to behave as expected.

Answer (score 2):

Since zebra_time's datatype is DATE, it actually contains the date and time part. The time part is just not displayed, because of your NLS settings. So, if the time part is different between each zebra_time, even when you group by zebra_time, you would get multiple rows.

Try:

```
select
  to_char(next_day(zebra_time, 'mon'), 'MM/DD/YYYY HH12:MI:SS AM'),
from builds
where
    zebra_time >= '01-jan-2014'
group by to_char(next_day(zebra_time, 'mon'), 'MM/DD/YYYY HH12:MI:SS AM');
```

And

```
select
  trunc(next_day(zebra_time, 'mon')),
from builds
where
    zebra_time >= '01-jan-2014'
group by trunc(next_day(zebra_time, 'mon'));
```

TRUNC removes the time part and groups by only the date.

References:
[Another SO related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17223226/oracle-how-to-output-date-and-time)