# Why does the SQL timestamp not print the time?

Tags: plsql

I created a column with a data type DATE and I inserted a row of record showing the current date and time. However, the record only reflected the current date and not the time. What can I do to reflect both the date and time?

```
insert into TFCC_EVENT_LOG(logged_time) values (select CURRENT_TIMESTAMP from dual);
```

I have tried to use the code below but it returns an error as shown below.

```
insert into TFCC_EVENT_LOG(id,userid,menu, action, description, status, logged_time) values (TEL_pk.nextval,'ngis', 'New TFCC Submission', 'New TFCC', 'New Submission Started', 'Success', (select to_char(logged_time, 'DD-MON-YYYY HH:M:SS PM') from TFCC_EVENT_LOG));
```

Error starting at line : 62 in command -
insert into TFCC_EVENT_LOG(id,userid,menu, action, description, status, logged_time) values (TEL_pk.nextval,'ngis', 'New TFCC Submission', 'New TFCC', 'New Submission Started', 'Success', (select to_char(logged_time, 'DD-MON-YYYY HH:M:SS PM') from TFCC_EVENT_LOG))
Error report -
ORA-01821: date format not recognized

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Oracle. How to output date and time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17223226/oracle-how-to-output-date-and-time)

Comment: Hi Tim. Thank you for recommending me to read that. I've tried the recommended approach in that thread but to no avail.

Comment: What's the specific error? What database are you using?

Comment: Hi technogeek1995! I have included the error message in my post. Please review and advise me. Thanks.

Comment: Can you please give the data type of column 'logged_time' in your table?

Comment: data type is DATE. I am using PL SQL

Comment: I gave an answer below please check that !

Comment: @Samuel "PL/SQL" is not a database.

Answer (score 0):

What really helped me was the alteration of session.

```
alter session set nls_date_format = 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS';
```

Comment: To display 12hr format use "alter session set nls_date_format = 'DD-MM-YYYY HH:MI:SS AM';

Answer (score 0):

`current_timestamp` returns a `timestamp`, not a `date`, so although it should get converted safely it would be better to use `sysdate` unless you specifically want the time zone semantics. Timestamps are fine things but they open the door to a host of issues around session vs server time zones, so I would advise using them with caution and plenty of testing.

Once you have a `date` value in the table, to copy it to another table you should not attempt to manipulate it with character functions. `to_date()` takes a character string, so using it on a date invokes an implicit conversion to a character string using the session’s default territory and format settings, which can have unpredictable results.

Client-side tools may use `nls_date_format` or their own settings to display date values. If you don’t see a time component it is most likely a display formatting issue.

Answer (score -1):

In your query you try to change the time stamp in a specific format using `to_char` function but the given format is wrong . You have to give the format as **'DD-MON-YYYY HH:MI:SS PM'**

Plese try the following code:

```
insert into TFCC_EVENT_LOG(id,userid,menu, action, description, status, logged_time) values (TEL_pk.nextval,'ngis', 'New TFCC Submission', 'New TFCC', 'New Submission Started', 'Success', (select to_char(logged_time, 'DD-MON-YYYY HH:MI:SS PM') from TFCC_EVENT_LOG));
```

Comment: Hi, I tried implementing your code and it returned ORA-01830: date format picture ends before converting entire input string error.