# SQL, creating date column with milliseconds

Tags: sql, oracle, date, create-table

I am trying to create a date column for my database which contains milliseconds.

How do I create a coloumn to store a date in the following format: YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS:FF3 ??

Thank You .

Comment: declare the column datatype as Datetime2 if using Sql server 2008 and above.

Comment: Which Database are you using?Read the documentation of your DBMS to check what datatypes it offers.

Comment: Hi, datetime2 was not recognised as a data type. Thanks

Comment: Hi Eat, I am trying to create a table using oracle for toad. Thanks

Comment: You should still go and read the documentation. Oracle docs are extensive and generally well written.

Comment: You should be using TIMESTAMP. Refer the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/sql_elements001.htm#SQLRF30020) for various datatypes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Oracle, `timestamp` stores the date and time down to (and beyond) milliseconds.

[Oracle date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/187474/oracle-date)

Comment: Hi, Thank you. This worked. Is it possible to specify a format for this column? I want to save the values in the following format: YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS:FFF.

Comment: @user3588388 - dates and timestamps don't have any format - it's the *string representation* that has a format. Use `TO_CHAR` to specify the format when converting from a date/timestamp to a string, e.g. when displaying it on screen or in a report.