# How to change the Hour value stored in Oracle Date variable?

Tags: oracle

I need to change the hour value of data stored in the Date variable.Is this possible in Oracle ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Oracle date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/187474/oracle-date)

Comment: I guess you'll have to update the complete value.

Comment: it's stored as a single value, the day/time - just use an UPDATE statement. If you're lazy, you can use SQL Developer's date editor - it has a hour field you can toggle up or down.

Comment: I need to update the time but, need to store it as Date Variable only.How to do that with UPDATE command ?

Answer (score 3):

**Oracle Setup**

```
CREATE TABLE your_table ( value DATE );

INSERT INTO your_table VALUES ( SYSDATE );
```

**Add one hour to the date**:

```
UPDATE your_table
SET value = value + INTERVAL '1' HOUR;
```

**Change the hour to 8am** (without changing the year/month/day/minute/second):

```
UPDATE your_table
SET value = value + NUMTODSINTERVAL(
                      8 - EXTRACT( HOUR FROM CAST ( value AS TIMESTAMP ) ),
                      'HOUR'
                    );
```

**To set the time to a new time**:

Change the time from the current value to `14:56:27`:

```
UPDATE your_table
SET value = TO_DATE(
              TO_CHAR( value, 'yyyy-mm-dd' ) || ' 14:56:27',
              'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'
            )
```

or

```
UPDATE your_table
SET value = TRUNC( value ) + INTERVAL '14:56:27' HOUR TO SECOND;
```